# How to implement a WebView inside a desktop app for macOS and Windows?

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, webview, cross-platform

I am trying to implement a WebView inside a desktop app that will run on both macOS and Windows. However, I have encountered issues with the three plugins that I have tried:

- webview_cef: does not support keyboard (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_cef).
- webview_windows: does not support macOS (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_windows).
- desktop_webview_window: opens another application while my app runs in the background (https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_webview_window).

Can anyone suggest a way to implement this that will work on both macOS and Windows, without the issues I've encountered with these plugins? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please help me out of this.

Comment: I know it's a bit late but do you still need ?